# Auto fill and submit HTML form and view in UIWebView iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios10

```
- (void)completeUserFieldsForWebView:(UIWebView *)webView withUsername:(NSString *)username {

    NSString *loadUsernameJS =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='text']\"); \
     for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", username];
    NSString *loadText =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='text']\"); \
     for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", username];

     NSLog(@"loadUsernameJS%@",loadUsernameJS);
     NSLog(@"loadText%@",loadText);

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadUsernameJS];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadText];

    NSLog(@"%@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadUsernameJS]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadText]);

}
- (void)completePasswordFieldsForWebView:(UIWebView *)webView withPassword:(NSString *)password {

    NSString *loadPasswordJS =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var passFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='password']\"); \
     for (var i = passFields.length>>> 0; i--;) { passFields[i].value ='%@';}", password];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadPasswordJS];

}
- (void)clickOnSubmitButtonForWebView:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString *performSubmitJS = @"var passFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='submit']\"); \
    passFields[0].click()";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:performSubmitJS];

}
```

This is working fine except the problem I am facing when the username is having slash b (i.e,\b) for e.g. test\btest it's only setting the username as testtest .As a result every time I am getting incorrect username .Please help me as I don't have too much knowledge in javascript. I was thinking it's only because of \b .But a username may contain \b .So in that case how to handle this situation .

Comment: You need to surround that code in the code tag

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.